# How could I call the getter function by using web3.js without the abi?

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

I am learning for using web3.js to interact with contract. And I would like to know
How to interact a Smart contract without abi?

Below is my contarct code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract sc {
    
    bool public opening = true;
    uint256 public a = 5;
    uint256 private b = 88;

    function test(uint256 a_, uint256 b_) pure public returns(uint) {
        return a_ + b_;
    }

    function test2(uint256 a_, uint256 b_) payable public returns(uint) {
        require(msg.value == 1, "Value is wrong");
        return a_ + b_;
    }

    function test3() public {
        opening = false;
    }

    fallback() external {}

}
```

and my Javascript code is:

```js
const { Web3 } = require('web3')
const { Tx } = require('ethereumjs-tx')
const rpcURL = "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/My API KEY"

const web3 = new Web3(rpcURL)
const address = "0xaAddr"
const MyAddr = "0xAddr"

functionSig = {
    name: "opening",
    type: "function"
}
const sig = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(functionSig)
var test = () => {
    web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:MyAddr,to:address,data: sig}).then(console.log)
}
test()
```

When executing this javascript code, I would like to see a result "true".
How should I fix my code ?

Comment: you cannot.  you should read this :https://www.quicknode.com/guides/ethereum-development/smart-contracts/what-is-an-abi